# How to deserialize a generic object at runtime with Jackson

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

Say I have the following java classes (getters & setters omitted for brevity).

```
public class AllMyEvents {
    private List<SomeEvent<?>> eventList;
}

public class SomeEvent<T> {
    private long time;

    @JsonProperty("event_type")
    private String eventType;

    @JsonProperty("event_data")
    private T eventData;    
}

public class BigEvent {
    private List<SomeEvent<LittleEvent>> subEvents;
}

public class LittleEvent {
    private long data;
}
```

When I call:

```
ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
AllMyEvents events = om.readValue(IOUtils.toString(jsonData, "UTF-8"),AllMyEvents.class);
```

The field `eventData` is of type `LinkedHashMap`.  What I want is for this fields type to be specified by the `eventType` string.  If the string is `'big'` I want `eventData` to have type `BigEvent` or `LittleEvent` if the string is `'little'`.

Is it possible to do this with Jackson annotations, or will I need to write a custom serializer/deserializer, or some other method?  I'm using Jackson 1.9 if that is relevant.

Comment: This is possible with jackson annotations, I have done this before. Let me see if I can find the code...

Comment: Could you show your `JSON`?

Answer (score 0):

Json Sub types is your answer.

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use=JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include=JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property="@class")
    @JsonSubTypes({
              @JsonSubTypes.Type(value=BigEvent.class, name="big"),
              @JsonSubTypes.Type(value=LittleEvent.class, name="little")
        })
public class SomeEvent<T> {
    private long time;

    @JsonProperty("event_type")
    private String eventType;

    ...
```

Also see: http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonPolymorphicDeserialization

Comment: I'm getting a: AssertionFailedError: Unexpected token (END_OBJECT), expected FIELD_NAME: missing property 'eventType' that is to contain type id  (for class com.blah.SomeEvent)

Also, Is it possible to put the annotations in the SomeEvent class?

Thanks!

Comment: @Doug Try the edit. I am not a pro at this, so I am just mudding my way through. Note: the annotation is now before the class event. I am not sure if it is possible to have the annotations IN the class since the SomeEvent is the superType. You might want to read up on jacksons polymorphism